# Association problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails. So i think i have association problems.

Given the three model classes with their associations:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_groups
  has_many :products, :through=>:product_groups
end

# product_group.rb
class ProductGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :user
end

# product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_group
  has_one :user
end
```

So when i trying add new product. I get errors.

```
# products_controller.rb
  def new
    @product = current_user.product_groups.products.build
  end
```

The errors I'm receiving is:

```
   NoMethodError (undefined method `products' for #<Class:0x2ca50b0>):
     app/controllers/products_controller.rb:27:in `new'
     -e:2:in `load'
     -e:2
```

I'm confused, can anybody help me? Or any different idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have the

```
has_many :products, :through=>:product_groups
```

you can do just

```
def new
   @product = current_user.products.build
end
```